# Accessing objects members in Java

Tags: java, object, global

I am confused as to how I create instances of an object I am defining and how to access their fields. Full code below. My class is called compressedString and I made a constructor:

```
public CompressString(char let, int appears){
    char letter = let;
    int  freq = appears;
}
```

later in my code i try and access the fields letter and freq after removing CompressString objects from a linked list, but that's where I run into trouble.

```
    CompressString tempNode;

    for(int j = 0; j<compressedString.length; j+=2){
        tempNode = list.pop();
        array[j] = tempNode.letter;
        array[j+1] = tempNode.freq;
    }
```

Eclipse gave me an error until I made class level variables for letter and freq. Why do I need class level variables to access these fields and will I just be overwriting them every time i pop a node from my linked list of these objects?

Here is the full code:

```
public class CompressString{

private char freq = 0;
private char letter;


public CompressString(char let, int appears){
    char letter = let;
    int  freq = appears;
}

public static void main(String[] argv){
    String str = "aaabbbccc";
    String str1 = "abc";
    String str2 = "abbbcccaaacccbbbccccc";

    System.out.println(compress(str));
    System.out.println(compress(str1));
    System.out.println(compress(str2));
}


private static String compress(String str){
    LinkedList<CompressString> list = new LinkedList();
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    char temp = array[0];
    int i = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    while(i<array.length){
        if(temp != array[i]){
            CompressString node = new CompressString(temp, counter);
            list.add(node);
        }
        temp = array[i];
        counter = 1;
        i++;
    }

    char[] compressedString = new char[list.size()*2];
    CompressString tempNode;
    for(int j = 0; j<compressedString.length; j+=2){
        tempNode = list.pop();
        compressedString[j] = tempNode.letter;
        compressedString[j+1] = tempNode.freq;
    }

    str = Arrays.toString(compressedString);
    return str;

}
}
```

Right now it only prints blanks

Comment: Fields **are** "class level variables" (well, more correctly, "object level variables").

Comment: You are only defining new variables. You've defined fields in your class: `private char freq = 0; private char letter;`, but in your constructor, you're never use the fields, you only define new variables. See the answer of @ElliotFrisch.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor isn't setting field values, only local values. This

```
public CompressString(char let, int appears){
  char letter = let;
  int  freq = appears;
}
```

Should be

```
public CompressString(char let, int appears){
  this.letter = let;
  this.freq = appears;
}
```

Also make sure `freq` and `letter` are marked as `public`, or define methods such as `getFreq()` and `getLetter()` if you haven't already.

Comment: @user137717 Those are not global variables. Global variables would be `public static` (not `private` class fields).

Comment: In my opinion, the word 'global' should not be used in Java context.